# Android app to detach any app from the Google Play Store

Tags: android, play-store

Can anyone recommend an Android app that allows the user to detach any app from the Google Play Store?

The reason to do this is to prevent updates to the target app (while preserving the usefulness of the Play Store's *Update All* function).

Titanium Backup is supposed to have this functionality, but it does not work on many KitKat ROMs.

Must be Android KitKat compatible.  Can assume root privileges.  Gratis preferred, but recommendations for paid apps are also welcomed.

Comment: Just have a look at [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=49418311&postcount=13)

Comment: @wingedpanther Thank you!  Will give it a try if no one comes up with an app to do all (or most) of the steps.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what w͏̢in̡͢g͘̕ed̨p̢͟a͞n͏͏t̡͜͝he̸r̴ suggested in comments earlier but all in one app.

You can resign apps with [Lucky Patcher](https://www.luckypatchers.com/download/) (root required).
Here are exact steps to tap inside the app:
Long tap on app name > Create Modified APK file > Re-sign with test signature. > Go to file > Install > Yes > Yes

Last Yes removes original app and installs modified one.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any way to get this to work with pre-installed apps?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Lucky Patcher can operate system apps too (if you're brave enough :). Also it has option in Long tap menu to move app to /system/app in case you want it to be system app after resigning.